# Haskell list of integers to [5,5,5] -> [555] without Data.Lists.Split

Tags: haskell

`Data.Lists.Split` is actually not working winHugs interpreter. which can be get by `splitEvery 3 ['a'..'z']` function

is it possible to achieve this without `Data.Lists.Split` ?
list of separate integers `[5,5,5,6,6,6]` -> to be `[555,666]`  to **concat** every three numbers !

should be **[Int]->[Int]**

Comment: Please notice that `split` operates on *lists*. An integer is for reasons of efficiency not a list.

Comment: @FUZxxl: But a list of integers is a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Possible Solution:

Here is one possible solution, using only function from the Prelude:

```
group3 :: [Int] -> [Int]
group3 [] = []
group3 xs = toSingleNum (take 3 xs): (group3 (drop 3 xs))
     where toSingleNum ys = read $ concat $ map show ys
```

There are, of course, innumerable ways to do this.  This is one.

---

### Explanation:

`group3` works by using the `take` and `drop` functions and natural recursion to split the list into groups of 3, and applying `toSingleNum` to each of the groups.

Ignoring the application of `take` and `drop`, the function works roughly as below:

```
group3 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
toSingleNum [1,2,3] : group3 [4,5,6,7,8,9]
toSingleNum [1,2,3] : toSingleNum [4,5,6] : group3 [7,8,9]
toSingleNum [1,2,3] : toSingleNum [4,5,6] : toSingleNum [7,8,9] : group3 []
toSingleNum [1,2,3] : toSingleNum [4,5,6] : toSingleNum [7,8,9] : []
```

After `toSingleNum` is applied, we'd have:

```
123 : 456 : 789 : []
[123, 456, 789]
```

---

`toSingleNum` converts a list of numbers into a single number.

```
toSingleNum [1, 3, 4]
>>> 134
toSingleNum [12, 13, 14]
>>> 121314
```

The conversion in `toSingleNum` is done by converting the numbers to a `String`, then combining them, then converting back to a number.

```
toSingleNum [1, 3, 4]
read $ concat $ map show [1, 3, 4]
read $ concat $ ["1", "3", "4"]
read $ "134"
134
```

---

### Further Reading:

If you're interested in Haskell, I'd recommend Graham Hutton's excellent "Programming in Haskell", or one of the tutorials listed on the [Haskell Wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tutorials).

Comment: @Sudantha Maybe you should ask a question about what you don't understand! That hopefully will give you the insight to learn to solve these questions yourself...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's quite possible. You can proceed like this:

- First write a function that takes three digits and "concat"s them into one number (this is quite easy using multiplication and addition).
- Then you write another function which takes a list and processes its elements in threes using the previous function. Basically the definition of that function will look like the definition of map, except that you process three elements instead of one in the non-empty case (i.e. you use a pattern like `x1:x2:x3:xs`), and you call the previously defined function instead of one given as an argument.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an implementation of `splitEvery` that should work for your purposes:

```
import Data.List

splitEvery _ [] = []
splitEvery n xs = chunk : splitEvery n remaining
    where (chunk, remaining) = splitAt n xs
```

Comment: actually this provides a list of list of int `[Int]->[[Int]]` i required it to be `[Int->Int]`

Comment: @Sudantha: hammar's function will give you the same functionality you would have gotten from `Data.List.Split.splitEvery`. From there you can proceed as you would if `Data.List.Split` were available to you.

Answer (score 3):

Let's make a general function that groups a given number of items, and applies a given function to each group.

```
groupMap :: ([a] -> b) -> Int -> [a] -> [b]
groupMap f n xs = go xs
    where go [] = []
          go xs = f (take n xs) : go (drop n xs)
```

OK, now what `f` should we pass in?

```
intListToInt :: [Int] -> Int
intListToInt xs = go xs 0
    where go []     v = v
          go (x:xs) v = go xs (x + v*10)
```

There are various different ways you could write this; I'm experimenting with the workhorse helper technique. Note that this type signature lines up nicely with the first argument of `groupMap`. Anyways...let's see if it works!

```
ghci> groupMap intListToInt 3 [5,5,5,6,6,6]
[555,666]
```

Yay! It even works for other stuff too. (some sketchy uses follow...)

```
ghci> groupMap (read :: String -> Int) 5 "1234554321"
[12345,54321]
ghci> groupMap (read :: String -> Bool) 4 "TrueTrueTrue"
[True,True,True]
ghci> groupMap sum 2 [1,2,3,4,5,6]
[3,7,11]
```

---

NB: If I'm not mistaken, `intListToInt` could benefit from a little more strictness:

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

intListToInt xs = go xs 0
    where go []     !v = v
          go (x:xs) !v = go xs (x + v*10)
```

Though I'm not at all familiar with which language pragmas Hugs supports.

Answer (score 2):

Use `show`, `concat` and `read`:

```
map (read . (>>= show)) . splitEvery 3
```

Comment: This will just concatenate all the digits in the list into one number. It's supposed to work in chunks of 3. That's why the OP mentioned `Data.Lists.Split.splitEvery`.

Answer (score 0):

First, split the list into chunks:

```
chunk n = unfoldr split
  where
    split [] = Nothing  -- stop
    split xs = Just $ splitAt n xs  -- keep going
```

```
ghci> chunk 3 [1..6]
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

The `chunk` function continues chopping `n`-sized chunks off the input list, until the list is empty. ([`unfoldr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.6.0.1/doc/html/Data-List.html#v%3aunfoldr) is one of the most under-appreciated functions in the standard library, by the way.)

Then turn each chunk into a number:

```
cumulate = foldl' (\x y -> x * 10 + y) 0
```

```
ghci> cumulate [4,5,6]
456
```

Now, compose these two functions together:

```
coalesce = map cumulate . chunk
```

```
ghci> coalesce [5,5,5,6,6,6]
[555,666]
```